# How to overwrite or edit results of FILTER text without erring in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm filtering a larger sheet into a smaller sheet using the `=FILTER` formula. I set up my filter successfully, like so:

```
=FILTER(form!A3:M3, NOT(ISBLANK(form!A3:M3)))
```

My only condition was that I filter in results from the larger sheet to the smaller one as long as it's not empty, but that point aside, **the problem is this**:

Once the data is in the smaller sheet, **I want to be able to edit cells in the smaller sheet ONLY. Right now, when I edit a cell in the smaller sheet, it errs because I'm overwriting the `=FILTER` result**.

I know I can "copy + paste as values only" but I'm wondering if there's a formula I can combine with my current formula that would output the results of `=FILTER` automatically as values and not the result of the said formula. I have tried to use `=TO_TEXT` and `=TEXT` in conjunction with my formula to no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, such functionality does not exist. most likely your only possible option 
(apart from <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> ... <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) is to use `FILTER` via script to print the result into cells as values instead of reference.